# Django image only showing in some pages

Tags: django

I have some problems in django, 
I can load images in my index.html, but not in other templates,
why is this happening?
Tried many methods and viewed many other post but non work for me.

This is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
 url(r'^$', 'userboard.views.home', name='home'),

 url(r'^items/(?P<UserBoard_id>\d+)/$','userboard.views.details',name='details'),

 url(r'^upload.html$', 'userboard.views.upload', name='upload'),

 url(r'^items/(?P<UserBoard_id>\d+)/delete.html$','userboard.views.delete',name='delete'),

 url(r'^items/(?P<UserBoard_id>\d+)/edit.html$','userboard.views.edit',name='edit'),

 url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

This is my index.html, it works fine

```
<h1> Your Items: </h1>


<ul>
{% for items in ItemList  %}
        <li><a href="/items/{{items.id}}/">
        <img src="{{items.itemImage}}"></a>
        </li>
        <hr />

{% endfor %}
</ul>
    <a href="/upload.html">Add a new item </a>
```

but this wont load my pictures

```
<img src="{{item.itemImage}}">

<h1>{{item.itemName}}<h1>
<h2>{{item.itemDesc}}</h2>
<br /><br/><br/>

<a href="{% url 'delete' item.id %}">Delete this item</a>
<br />
<a href="{% url 'edit' item.id %}">Edit this item </a>
```

i am not sure if you need my views, here they are

```
def home ( request) :
ItemList= models.UserBoard.objects.all()
return render_to_response('index.html',{'ItemList':ItemList})


def details(request,UserBoard_id):
try:
    item=models.UserBoard.objects.get(pk=UserBoard_id)
except models.UserBoard.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
return render_to_response('details.html' ,{'item':item})
```

Please let me know where I went wrong or at least give me a hint where I could start searching on.

EDIT:

here are my models

```
from django.db import models


class UserBoard(models.Model):
itemName=models.CharField(max_length=100)
itemDesc=models.CharField(max_length=400)
itemImage=models.ImageField(upload_to='../media/pictures')
```

if i print out the value of items.itemImage, it will show this ../media/pictures/d.jpg
Same value in both pages, but image will only show on 1. Templates for both pages are at the same folder.

And here is my settings.py media root

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/rox/Documents/IP/userboard/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED**
THANKS A LOT to little_birdie and the others out there who helped.
The problem was this . I didn't put the '/' infront of item.itemImage previously.

However, why is it that without the / it works in the index.html but not the others?

Comment: First, just print out the variable ``{{item.itemImage}}`` on those templates where it does not work to ensure the value is correct. Then – what kind of URLs is provided by item.itemImage – absolute or relative?

Comment: could you add your models? Is the image in a ImageField or what?

Comment: Could you also post your MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT from your settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite enough information but I think I know what's going on here.

You are getting a relative path from item.itemImage, that is.. it does not start with a slash, so the browser will load it relative to the url of the page the image is on.

Apparently you stored the full url path to your image in your image field, eg:
media/foo/myphoto.jpg

When loaded from / (home page) becomes '/media/foo/myphoto.jpg'.. which works.

The bottom line is, do this:

```
<img src="/{{item.itemImage}}">
```

Comment: Like you said, there isn't enough information to answer the question.  The comments are for requesting more information.  You shouldn't just be guessing wildly.

Comment: Additionally, if that was the case then it would be advisable to check how ``itemImage`` is populated. Chances are that django's static- or media-urls are not used which is just an easy and sane way to provide the option to easily switch the storage backends/media paths in the future.

Comment: That's not very nice.

Comment: Neither is unhelpful guessing.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is just the img src='/ problem, but why is it that i do not need to / in index, but i need to use / in other templates?

Comment: prepending a slash is called an absolute path.  without one it is called relative.  so when you're in the index, the relative path and absolute path are the same.  when you use an absolute path on any other url, it goes back to the root and searchs for the path from there